# Firebase Crashlytics List all Issue

Tags: firebase, crashlytics

I have to do some reports on how many crashed issue for a project happened in a week. And the project that I am working on have more than 100 issue per week. Is there any way I can get the issue name, URL, carshed number and user number via API or other ways? I know Crashlytics support exporting crash data to BigQuery. And I might be able to do some analysis from there but it is not free of charge.